# apache2 is not starting

Tags: apache2, logs

```
Starting web server apache2
(99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 10.0.1.43:8069
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, "`(99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 10.0.1.43:8069
no listening sockets available, shutting down`". Some other process has allocated the socket you are trying to make Apache use (probably an earlier attempt to start Apache).

Find out which process has TCP port 8069 open with:

```
sudo lsof -i :8069
```